# Integration in the context of modelling with the Meixner Process

Tags: mathematics, numerical-methods

I failed to evaluate the integral of $\frac{e^{ax}}{x\sinh(bx)}$ with respect to $x$ from negative infinite to positive infinite. What techniques can I use to evaluate the integrals of such kind for the Meixner Levy process for the purpose of numerical analysis?

Comment: could you perhaps provide some more context ? Why do you need to integrate the function mentioned above in order to model the process ?

Comment: Is this question relevant to quant finance?

Answer (score 2):

The integral diverges, hence numerical integration will not yield a meaningful result.

Indeed, using the [Taylor expansion of the hyperbolic sine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function#Taylor_series_expressions) one has that  $$x \sinh (bx)= x\frac{e^{bx}-e^{-bx}}{2}=bx^2+\frac{b^3x^4}{6}+...$$
Therefore, at the vicinity of $x=0$
$$\frac{e^{ax}}{x \sinh (bx)}\sim\frac{1}{bx^2}$$
which is a non-integrable singularity even in terms of [the Cauchy principal value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value).

Comment: I must humbly concede that you are correct